# Importing Images with Labels using addImageToMediaGallery

Tags: image, import, ce-1.9.0.0

I am assigning multiple images onto a product in my magento store with the below:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

$images_array = array("image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg");
$_product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));

$i = 1;
foreach($images_array as $img){
    $img_url = $path.$img;
    if(file_exists($img_url)){
        if($i==1){
            $_product->addImageToMediaGallery ($img_url, array ('thumbnail','small_image','image'), false, false);
        }else{
            $_product->addImageToMediaGallery ($img_url, null, false, false);
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

I am missing the ability to set the image label during the `addImageToMediaGallery` method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need update label after image save

```
foreach($product->getData('media_gallery') as $each){

    foreach($each as $image) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($image);
        echo "</pre>";  
        $i++;

        $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getSetAttributes($product);
    $attributes['media_gallery']->getBackend()->updateImage($product, $image['file'], $data=array('position'=>$i,'label'=>$image['file']));
    }
}

$product->save();
```

Comment: Very nice solution, thanks. Do you also happen to know how to add a label for different storeviews? Like for example I want our English storeview to have an English image label string and our Dutch storeview a Dutch image label.